# How to extract data from excel file into the database in Mysql at runtime in asp.net?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, excel, import

I am creating a website...and i want to give a liberty to users, to upload the data of excel file and then i want to save that excel data inside mysql database on runtime...

kindly help me in performing this task...
you can mail me at...."amiteshsinha09@rediffmail.com"

thank you
Amitesh

Comment: @Amitesh: Please take a few moments to see how other people ask the questions. The title of the question should be same as "subject" in case of an email. The bigger box should describe the problem in a way, whereby it has all the necessary information necessary for people to help you. Also, you should come and check in this forum for answers to your question. Do not expect people to email you the solution.

Comment: @Amitesh: What do you mean by data of excel file? Any specific sheet? range? Can the mysql table be mapped to your excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the data in the excel sheet using [Open Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824.aspx)

Using this instead of running Excel via interop is both faster, more stable and saves you licence costs.